# saving into sqlite database in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I want to save the records into SQLite database in the android studio, but I get an error at the catch exception. Please I want help with this code. Thank you

```
public void saveData() {
        try {

            SQLiteDatabase database = openOrCreateDatabase("FARM", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cart(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, transno VARCHAR(100),  pcode VARCHAR(100),  pdes VARCHAR(100), price VARCHAR(100), qty VARCHAR(50),  disc VARCHAR(50),  total VARCHAR(100), vendorId VARCHAR(100), vendorName VARCHAR(100), vendorPlace VARCHAR(100), sdate date, saleperson VARCHAR(100), status VARCHAR(100));";
            database.execSQL(sql);

            //String qu = " INSERT INTO cart(transno, pcode, pdes, price, qty, disc, total, vendorId, vendorName, vendorPlace, sdate, saleperson, status) VALUES('"+transNo+"','"+saleCode+"','"+saleProduct+"','"+salePrice+"','"+saleQty+"','"+saleDisc+"','"+saleTotal+"', '"+custId+"','"+custName+"','"+custPlace+"','"+dateDaily+"','"+salePerson+"','"+status+"')";
            String qu = "insert into cart (transno, pcode, pdes, price, qty, disc, total, vendorId, vendorName, vendorPlace, sdate, saleperson, status) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(qu);
            statement.bindString(1, transNo);
            statement.bindString(2, saleCode);
            statement.bindString(3, saleProduct);
            statement.bindString(4, salePrice);
            statement.bindString(5, saleQty);
            statement.bindString(6, saleDisc);
            statement.bindString(7, saleTotal);
            statement.bindString(8, custId);
            statement.bindString(9, custName);
            statement.bindString(10, custPlace);
            statement.bindString(11, dateDaily);
            statement.bindString(12, userid);
            statement.bindString(13, status);

            statement.execute();
            Toast.makeText(activity, "New Sale Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            product.getEditText().setText("");
            price.getEditText().setText("");
            quant.getEditText().setText("");
            disc.getEditText().setText("");



        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "error occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I get an error at the catch exception. It also does not save